# How to add background image to complete view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. I want to design a custom view with few controls and a background image. The background image should cover the complete view. It should look like a watermark for the screen. How can I achieve this using SwiftUI?

Answer (score 48):

Use `ZStack` but **Don't use `UIScreen`**:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Image("BG")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

        Text("Hello world")
    }
}
```

Using `UIScreen` will lead your app to undesired behavior if you are supporting multiscreen app, resizable windows, multiwindow app, etc.

Comment: But how to make the Text (in my case I have some scrollview) that does not ignore safe area?

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
    var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Text("Hello")
    }
    .background(
        Image("Background")
            .resizable()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    )
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE**

with iOS 15 Xcode 13.2

```
public extension View {
    func fullBackground(imageName: String) -> some View {
       return background(
                Image(imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
       )
    }
}
```

use

```
YourView
.fullBackground(imageName: "imageName")
```

**END UPDATE**

**OLD ANSWER**

I prefer a @ViewBuilder

**Usage:**

```
BackgroundView(imageName: "image name") {         
     Text("Hello")                               
}
```

**@ViewBuilder**

```
public struct BackgroundView <Content : View> : View {
    public var content : Content
    public var imageName: String
    public var opacity: Double
    public init(imageName: String, opacity: Double=1,@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self.imageName = imageName
        self.opacity = opacity
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                Image(imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.height, alignment: .center)
                    .opacity(opacity)
                content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Mojtaba is incomplete. The problem is the bounding box of the image can exceed the screen leading to undesired behavior. To correct this we need to add `.frame` to the mix. This will make sure the image is as large as the screen and fixes our problem.

```
struct BackgroundView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            Image("Background")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
                .clipped()
        }.ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the full screen width and height, and you don't bother about the aspect ratio of the image, you can either use a geometry reader of the UIScreen size's.

```
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
```

This line of code will set the Image to the max size of the device. Depending on your parent view and device, you may need to use:

```
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

This will ignore the safe area's on iPhone X devices and above.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `ZStack` like below. You can add more control on `Image` for example I added `Text()`

```
var body: some View {
      ZStack{
           Image("your image")
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
           Text("Hello World").foregroundColor(.white).font(.system(size: 20)).bold()
       }
}
```

You can Ignore `SafeArea` using

```
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("imageName")
            .resizable()
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be much more useful if it explained how this code answers the question. The other answers to this question have good explanations. A new answer should provide new insights and good explanations.